# C++ Vector content is being deleted?

Tags: c++, vector

I've been trying to create a directed graph following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_TulH374hw

```
class Digraph {
public:
    Digraph();

    void addNode(Node);
    void addEdge(Edge);

    void print();

private:
    //This is a vector which contains a node source and a vector of node destinations
    vector< tuple< Node, vector<Node>>> nodes;
};
```

but after I add 2 nodes and a Edge it seems like the vector with the destinations is beeing emptied

```
void Digraph::addEdge(Edge e){
   Node src = e.getSrc();
   Node dest = e.getDest();

   for(auto node : nodes){
       if(get<0>(node).getName() == src.getName()){
           get<1>(node).push_back(dest);
           //cout << "added conection " << get<0>(node).getName() << " -> " << get<1>(node).back().getName() << " now "  << get<0>(node).getName() << " has " << get<1>(node).size() << " destinations" <<"\n";
           return;
       }
   }

   cout << "node " << src.getName() << " does not exist \n";
   return;
}

void Digraph::print(){
   for(auto node : nodes){
       get<0>(node).print();
       cout << " has " << get<1>(node).size() << " destinations";
       cout << "\n";
       for(auto destination : get<1>(node)){
           cout << "\t->";
           destination.print();
           cout << "\n";
       }
}
```

}

In main.cpp I add the nodes and the edge

```
graph.addNode(NY);
graph.addNode(CHICAGO);

graph.addEdge(road);
graph.print();
```

It ends up adding the edge succesfully but when it prints the final result it does not recognize the edge it just added

```
added conection NY -> Chicago now NY has 1 destinations
NY has 0 destinations
Chicago has 0 destinations
```

When tried with more Nodes and Edges I realized it never adds more than one Edge, maybe it has to do with how i defined the class? vectors is not the choice?

Comment: Are you accustomed to Java, by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `auto` in the for loop needs to be a reference (`auto&`), and after the code I'll tell you why.

```cpp
void Digraph::addEdge(Edge e){
   Node src = e.getSrc();
   Node dest = e.getDest();
   // use references here
   for(auto& node : nodes){
       if(get<0>(node).getName() == src.getName()){
           // now this modifies the original, not a copy
           get<1>(node).push_back(dest);
           //cout << "added conection " << get<0>(node).getName() << " -> " << get<1>(node).back().getName() << " now "  << get<0>(node).getName() << " has " << get<1>(node).size() << " destinations" <<"\n";
           return;
       }
   }

   cout << "node " << src.getName() << " does not exist \n";
   return;
}
```

The entire point of this function is to *change* the nodes in some way. If you iterate over them with `for (auto node : nodes)` you are getting a copy of each node. It's the same as `Node node : nodes`, the `auto` doesn't make a difference. You then call `push_back` on this copy, which gets destroyed as soon as the next loop iteration comes up.

Effectively, your original stays entirely untouched since you only take copies of it's member nodes, not *references*.

If you use a reference here like I did, you take a reference to each node in the `nodes` vector, and modify the reference, which modifies the original.

Comment: src and dest probably have the same problem. Every `push_back(dest)` makes a copy of dest

Comment: @user253751 that's true, and I was going to add it, but it's actually not part of the problem. But yes, @ OP you should be taking references, or const references, everywhere you can :)

Comment: You can't store references in vectors.

Comment: @user253751 of course not, and that's not what i'm saying :D You can obviously store a std::reference_wrapper, but that makes no sense here.

Comment: Yes, when I realized that I had forgotten to write the & I rewrote the rest of the for loops. Thanks!